# copy strings that match pattern from row in dataframe and put into new column in new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I need to find all the strings between certain characters in a row in column 1 in a 2 column dataframe in R. Then I need to put them into a new table or dataframe that has the instances in column 1 with the SAME column 2 values that were in the original dataframe next to column 1. 
Here is the example. I need to take  all the words between xx...xx in column 1 of dataframe foo.df and put them into a new table with column 2 showing the users that were in the appropriate row in foo.df:

We can make the dataframe this way:

```
text <- c('hello xxthisxx is a xxtestxx of','we xxarexx very happy','you will xxwantxx to help') 
user <- c('person1','person2','person3') 
foo.df <- data.frame(text,user)
```

BUT then I want to copy the words between the xx so the final result will look like this:

```
 text      user
 this   person1
 test   person1
 are    person2
 want   person3
```

Nothing I have tried seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` package to split and convert our data table to long format. After that, we filter on entries that have `xx...xx` format and finally remove leading and trailing `xx`, i.e.

```
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit(foo.df, 'text', ' ', 'long')[grepl('xx.*xx', text),][,text := gsub('xx(.*)xx', '\\1', text)][]
#   text    user
#1: this person1
#2: test person1
#3:  are person2
#4: want person3
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you so much for this helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tidyverse approach, using lookahead and lookbehid regex

```
library( tidyverse )
foo.df %>% 
  mutate( text = str_extract_all( text, '(?<=[\\s]xx).*?(?=xx[\\s])' ) ) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select( text, user )

#   text    user
# 1 this person1
# 2 test person1
# 3  are person2
# 4 want person3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `base R` option with `regmatches/gregexpr`

```
out <- stack(setNames(regmatches(foo.df$text, 
   gregexpr("(?<=xx)[^ ]+(?=xx)", foo.df$text, perl = TRUE)), foo.df$user))
names(out) <- names(foo.df)
out    
#  text    user
#1 this person1
#2 test person1
#3  are person2
#4 want person3
```